# Moving a file into a Google Drive folder without changing its ACL

Tags: google-drive-api

In Google Drive, when puting a file into a folder, the ACLs of the folder are added to the ACLs of the file.

Is there a way to avoid that? In my use case, a lot of user have "Can View" access on the folder, but only a subset of those will ultimately allowed to view that file. Even if we quickly follow with an ACL update request, there will be a short amount of time during which the visibility of the file is too broad for my use case.

Note that a solution involving having a short period of time during which the access is more limited that what it will ultimately be would be acceptable. Also, I am ready to use either Drive API or Document List API.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://gappstips.com/docs-tips/view/112/dont-forget-the-advanced-editor-sharing-settings) might help

I was so happy when I found it! Unfortunately, it still cannot override file settings, in the case of a document owned by someone else than the containing folder's creator.